# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'" on my list modifier function in Python 3

Tags: python, list, function, strip, nonetype

I'm a Python newbie. I'm trying to define a function that takes a string list and adds html tags to its elements. 
For example, it modifies:

```
list_1 = ["hey", "hello", "Joe"]
```

to

```
html_list = ["<ul>","<li>hey</li>", "<li>hello</li>", "<li>Joe</li>",> "</ul>"]
```

It is raising the following exception: 
***'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'***

Here's my code:

```
def html_list(input_list):
        for index in range(len(input_list)):
            input_list[index] = "<li>" + input_list[index] + "<li>"
        input_list.insert(0,"<ul>")
        input_list.append("<ul>")
        print(input_list)

list_1 = ["hey", "hello", "Joe"]
html_list(list_1)
```

Comment: This isn't where that error is coming from. Please post a [mcve] and the exact, complete error message that code produces, including the full stack trace.

Comment: Are you using the correct variable name when you pass the list to the function?

Comment: Sorry, it's not an error. It is raising an exception message

Comment: You don't return anything from your function, so your function returns `None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get your error but it may be stemming from the variable you created with the same name as the function `html_list`, perhaps?

I tested *this* code in python2 and python3 and it seems to work. I modified the code so that your function returns the `input_list`. It prints the output where it calls the function.

```py
list_1 = ["hey", "hello", "joe"]

def html_list(input_list):
    new_list = ["<ul>"]
    for item in input_list:
        new_list.append("<li>{}</li>".format(item))
    new_list.append("</ul>")
    return new_list

print(html_list(list_1))
```

Returns

```
['<ul>', '<li>hey</li>', '<li>hello</li>', '<li>joe</li>', '</ul>']
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. I tried your code and got the following message" _Your code raised an exception, "'list' object has no attribute 'strip'"_

Comment: What version of Python are you running? Also, did you try to copy and paste the above code into a new file and then run it using `python whateveryoucalledthefile.py` ?

Comment: I'm running the code on Udacity website, where I'm receiving the exception message. It is working fine elsewhere. Was just wondering why I'm receiving the exception message there.

Comment: Interesting. It's possible the Udacity website has a bug or some kind of issue with their python interpreter. If I were you, I'd contact their support and explain to them what's going on so they can resolve it.

Comment: thanks! I will do that